# Pandas pivot table to Bar Chart Preserving Hierarchy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pivot-table, hierarchical

Given the following pivot table:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],
                 'B':['x','y','z','x','y','z','x','y','z'],
                 'C':['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a'],
                 'D':[7,5,3,4,1,6,5,3,1]})
table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['A', 'B','C'],aggfunc='sum')
table

            D
A   B   C   
a   x   a   7
        b   4
    y   a   1
        b   5
    z   a   3
b   x   a   5
    y   b   3
    z   a   1
        b   6
```

I'd like to create a horizontal bar chart which preserves the hierarchical layout of the indices.

Currently, if I do this:

```
%matplotlib inline
a=table.plot(kind='barh')
a.show()
```

I get this:

[image]

But what I really want is something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

well it preserves hierarchy, but it's not exactly what you've plotted as your desired graph:

```
orig_index = table.index

idx = (a.apply(lambda row: '{} {} {}'.format(
                    row['a'] if a.shift(1).ix[row.name, 'a'] != row['a'] else ' ',
                    row['b'] if a.shift(1).ix[row.name, 'b'] != row['b'] else ' ',
                    row['c']), axis=1)
)

table.index = idx[::-1]

table.plot.barh()
```

[image]

Comment: I think I can use this if I can take one more step; if I can isolate every entry in index level 2 (using table.index.levels[2] gives unique values, but I need all values in order of appearance in the pivot table), and do the same for other levels, I'm thinking I can then plot them in a table a la plt.table() minus some lines.

Comment: I've posted a related question to that effect here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37190938/pandas-get-all-values-from-multiindex-level-2