# Pandas Get All Values from Multiindex levels

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pivot-table, multi-index

Given the following pivot table:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],
                 'B':['x','y','z','x','y','z','x','y','z'],
                 'C':['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a'],
                 'D':[7,5,3,4,1,6,5,3,1]})
table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['A', 'B','C'],aggfunc='sum')
table

            D
A   B   C   
a   x   a   7
        b   4
    y   a   1
        b   5
    z   a   3
b   x   a   5
    y   b   3
    z   a   1
        b   6
```

I'd like to access each value of 'C' (or level 2) as a list to use for plotting.
I'd like to do the same for 'A' and 'B' (levels 0 and 1) in such a way that it preserves spacing so that I can use those lists as well. I'm ultimately trying to use them to create something like this via plotting:
[image: What I'm ultimately trying to plot]

[Here's the question from which this one stemmed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173170/pandas-pivot-table-to-bar-chart-preserving-hierarchy/37173918#37173918)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry are you asking for `table.index.get_level_values(2)` or `table.index.get_level_values('C')` if you prefer?

Comment: That's it! Can you post as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html#pandas.Index.get_level_values) to get the index values at a specific level from a multi-index:

```
In [127]:
table.index.get_level_values('C')

Out[127]:
Index(['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], dtype='object', name='C')

In [128]:    
table.index.get_level_values('B')

Out[128]:
Index(['x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'z'], dtype='object', name='B')

In [129]:
table.index.get_level_values('A')

Out[129]:
Index(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'], dtype='object', name='A')
```

`get_level_values` accepts an int param for the level or a label

Note that for the higher levels, the values are repeated to correspond with the index length at the lowest level, for display purposes you don't see this

Comment: Just to add icing to the cake, can you demonstrate how to replace all values of level 'A' with '' save for the middle value (or upper middle value for even counts, such as the 2nd value from the top in the case of the 'b' values in level 'A')?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, are you asking how to compress the values so that for instance they don't repeat for a given level?

Comment: I just want to replace all values with blanks save for the middle ones for level 'A' (0) so that when I add them as secondary and tertiary axis labels (I'll post a question on how to do that shortly), they display lined up like in my example chart. I'd also like to do something similar with level 'B' (1) to preserve spacing.

Comment: I think you should post another question really

Comment: Okay, will do. Thanks!

Comment: Posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191784/pandas-replace-all-but-middle-values-per-category-of-a-level-with-blank